# How to get the unique rows from the different tables using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query in which getting the result from different product tables.for a single product there are different category.

```
    select    p.model as model,
              pd.name as product_name,
              p.price as price,
              c.category_id as category,
              p.weight as weight, 
              pd.description as description,
              p.image as image 

    from      ares_product p 
    join      ares_product_description pd on p.product_id = pd.product_id 
    join      ares_product_to_category c on p.product_id =c.product_id 
    order     by p.product_id.
```

by using this query iam getting the result like

```
-RXR16 Rain-X Repel 16" 10.0000 30 7.00000000 Rain-X Repel 16" data/newimages/Repel.jpg

-RXR16 Rain-X Repel 16" 10.0000 34 7.00000000 Rain-X Repel 16" data/newimages/Repel.jpg
```

for this the product is same but categories are different.

How can i get them in a single result like

```
-RXR16 Rain-X Repel 16" 10.0000 30,34 7.00000000 Rain-X Repel 16" data/newimages/Repel.jpg
```

Comment: See GROUP_CONCAT - or just handle the logic in the application code (e.g. a simple PHP loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    p.model as model,
    pd.name as product_name,
    p.price as price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_id) as category,
    p.weight as weight,
    pd.description as description,
    p.image as image
FROM ares_product p
JOIN ares_product_description pd
    ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
JOIN ares_product_to_category c
    ON p.product_id = c.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY p.product_id
```

Using `GROUP_CONCAT` and a `GROUP BY` clause you can get the results you want.